# Why is Rails returning a different float value when using a different database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app running Rails 4.2 with this migration

```
create_table "nutrient_amounts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "nutrient_id", limit: 4
  t.integer "food_id",     limit: 4
  t.float   "amount",      limit: 24
end
```

After running this migration using both SQLite and MySQL, I've added a row of data with `0.8` as the `amount` to both of them.

When I access amount in the console with SQLite as the database:

```
 >  NutrientAmount.find(1).amount
 => 0.8
```

When I access amount in the console with MySQL as the database:

```
>  NutrientAmount.find(1).amount
=> 0.800000011920929
```

If I open up MySQL in the terminal and run

```
mysql> SELECT amount FROM nutrient_amounts WHERE id = 1;
+--------+
| amount |
+--------+
|    0.8 |
+--------+
```

I'm confused here. Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't Rails be returning `0.8` when using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this issue - it was down to the adapter I was using inside `database.yml`.

I was using `mysql` so I upgraded to `mysql2`. `0.8` is returned as expected now.

Comment: That doesn't really solve your problem, it just pushes it elsewhere. Accounting for this sort of behavior is just part of working with floating point values, you'll have to face it head on sooner or later.

Comment: So what are you suggesting? That all code takes into account floating point values from the database that may not be returned rounded?

Comment: I'm suggesting that all code that deals with floating point values (regardless of where they come from) needs to understand how they work and how arithmetic with them works. You might want to be using `decimal` or `numeric` inside the database and `BigDecimal` in Ruby or switch everything to integers (if you can get away it).